# Проблема с фото wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Товар добавлен с помощью плагина woocomerce.
если фото открыть сверху меню, то видно меню сайта.

Как можно решить? Спасибо.

Comment: Этот вопрос никак не относится к Wordpress, а проблема решается через z-index.

Comment: Z-index не помог менял для фото и для меню.